# Error installing Jekyll While executing gem ... (TypeError) no implicit conversion

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I just started having this issue with installing Jekyll and have been scratching my head for a couple of days now. I have done a lot of research on trying to resolve this error but have not found a solution as of yet. I have tried rebooting into recovery mode and running the csrutil disable however, that did not work.

Mac OSX EL Capitan
version 10.11.6

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

Jekyll is about to finish the installation from what it looks like but then throughs this error. I am just not sure what to make of it?

If anyone can help I would appreciate it very much. I am falling behind on some work but things happen and you have to adjust.

Thank you for you help with this issue up front.

[jekyll] installation ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)     no implicit conversion

Please let me know if there is any information that I have forgotten to mention.

Here is the full installation to the error message:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ David$ sudo gem install jekyll
Password:
Fetching: liquid-3.0.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed liquid-3.0.6
Fetching: kramdown-1.11.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed kramdown-1.11.1
Fetching: mercenary-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mercenary-0.3.6
Fetching: safe_yaml-1.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed safe_yaml-1.0.4
Fetching: colorator-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed colorator-1.1.0
Fetching: rouge-1.11.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rouge-1.11.1
Fetching: sass-3.4.22.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.4.22
Fetching: jekyll-sass-converter-1.4.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-sass-converter-1.4.0
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.9.7
Fetching: ffi-1.9.14.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.14
Fetching: rb-inotify-0.9.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.9.7
Fetching: listen-3.0.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed listen-3.0.8
Fetching: jekyll-watch-1.5.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-watch-1.5.0
Fetching: forwardable-extended-2.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed forwardable-extended-2.6.0
Fetching: pathutil-0.14.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pathutil-0.14.0
Fetching: jekyll-3.2.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Comment: Full error message, or at least first three lines. Please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure how I have fixed the issue but I do think all those that posted on this issue. I will try and back track and figure out what the actual solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can your try :

```
gem install bundler
```

then

```
gem install jekyll
```

then

```
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Comment: Sorry, but I get the same error message. I am not sure what else is missing? Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Try to install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme). This will allows you to make very fresh ruby installations.

Comment: I installed the rbenv as suggested and have tried different versions of ruby. However, I am also finding if I try to install new versions of ruby gems, I am getting the same error. This has to be one crazy thing going on?